# Coplien form example C++

Tags: c++

I know a Coplien form is composed of:

- Constructor
- Destructor
- Copy constructor
- Operator overload `=`

But I don't know how to implement it each part of this form ...
I already know how to do *constructors* and *destructors*, because it is pretty simple like:

```
class Example
{
    public:

        /* Constructor  */
        Example();

        /* Destructor */
        ~Example();

        /* Copy constructor */

        /* Operation overload = */

};
```

I have a problem on:

```
-Copy constructor
-Operation overload
```

Can I have an example of the Coplien form to get it, please?

Comment: That's not valid C++. Also, what's a coplien form? And are you just asking how to declare a copy constructor and `operator=` overload?

Comment: A coplien's form is a model of declaration of a class. I dont get how to do Copy Constructor & Operation Overload. Why is this not valid c++ ?

Comment: Because `Class` should be `class` and you need a semi-colon after your class definition.

Comment: Well for one you wrote `Class` instead of `class`

Comment: Corrected but that's don't actually answer my question.

Comment: I've never actually heard of the Coplien form... As for each of the section you mentionned this is really basic. Maybe you should check your C++ book first and ask a more focused question?

Comment: AFAIK, coplien form is related to design patterns (uniform way to present them) and has nothing to do with classes at all (besides being used in those patterns maybe)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Coplien, and http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CanonicalForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy constructor is `Example(const Example&)` and the assignment operator is `Example& operator = (const Example& e)`. You can find some information on those [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/).